# Update current record within Python dataframe itertuples loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looping through a dataframe using itertuples per the below code extract.
For each record, I want to update the quantity (Qty) field in the file_B row so next time I loop through I'll be reading the updated quantity.

```
df_A = pd.read_csv('file_A.csv', header=0)
df_B = pd.read_csv('file_B.csv', header=0)

df_B = df_B.set_index(["PO", "Item"])
df_C = df_C.set_index(["PO", "Item"])

# Loop through file_A records
for rowA in df_A.itertuples():

    # Loop through file_B records
    for rowB in df_B.loc[(rowA.PO, rowA.Item)].itertuples():

        # subtract rowA qty from rowB qty
        rowB.Qty = rowB.Qty - rowA.Qty
        
        # do other stuff
        ...
        ...
        
        # update rowB qty
        ??? This is where I am stuck
```

I've tried various things with loc and iloc, but not sure if I'm on the right track and have not been able to update the current file_B record.

Comment: When you do `itertuples`, you are looking at a COPY of the data.  The data isn't natively stored as tuples.  Your first goal should be to find a way to do your operation in parallel.  Lacking that, try to use `apply`.  If those can't work, you may be forced to use `range(len(x))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what you do in section *"do other stuff"* but to update the quantity, you can do:

```
# Assume you set 'PO' and 'Item' as index of both dataframes
# df_A = df_A.set_index(['PO', 'Item'])
# df_B = df_B.set_index(['PO', 'Item'])

# Find common index (same PO, same Item)
idx = df_B.index.intersection(df_A.index)

# Update the quantity
df_B.loc[idx, 'Qty'] -= df_A.loc[idx, 'Qty']
```

Example:

```
>>> df_A
         Qty
PO Item     
A  b       2
B  c       4
   d       4
C  a       4
   b       4
D  c       2
   d       2

>>> df_B
         Qty
PO Item     
A  a      10  # missing in df_A, expected 10
   b      10  # qty=2 in df_A, expected 8
B  c      10  # qty=4 in df_A, expected 6


# After update
>>> df_B
         Qty
PO Item     
A  a      10
   b       8
B  c       6
```